# Web Application Internationalization, do it server-side .Net core with or client-side with react?

Tags: reactjs, .net, localization, internationalization, i18next

We are looking to internationalize a web application, we want to localize it to 14 languages.

Is it best to output localization Server-side (it is written in .net core C#) or Client-side (React)?

Incase of using client-side, we will handle it by using I18Next.

Incase of using server-side, we will handle it by the SQL or NoSQL database.

What is the best practice to follow regarding scalability and app performance?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best and most used i18n framework for React is indeed [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/).
In case you're new to it, there is a nice guide you can follow [here](https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/).

For [server-side](https://locize.com/blog/how-does-server-side-internationalization-look-like/) the biggest question is probably how you're going to manage the translations?
Will you use the client side and the server side translations in the same Translation Management System?
If so, is it possible to use different [i18n formats](https://locize.com/blog/i18n-formats-javascript/)?
If you want to also use the i18next format for .Net, it may be there is some .Net specific i18next library? [I18Next.Net](https://github.com/DarkLiKally/I18Next.Net) or [i18next-net](https://github.com/leonardobaggio/i18next-net)?

btw: there are some [other localization related questions](https://locize.com/blog/is-your-software-ready-for-localization/) that might help investigate best practices